# Can I use areal mean pixel value in raster for input to Extract Values to Point tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, resampling, correlation

I have a dataset consisting of a point vector file (plant leaf area) overlaid and georeferenced to a raster file (soil moisture) that I want to use as inputs to the **Extract Values To Point** Tool in ArcGIS 10.3. I want to investigate correlation between soil moisture values and plant leaf area.

**Is there a way to take the mean raster values of areas (defined by coordinate bounding box or radius circle) whose centerpoints correspond to the locations of the point features, and use those values as the raster input?** Comparing the mean value for a given area corresponding with the plant location strikes me as a more robust, and less computationally intensive, approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Filter](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qq000000.htm) tool in Spatial Analyst to smooth the underlying raster data. Then use the smoothed raster in your **Extract Values to Point** tool.

For more flexibility you could use the [Focal Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Focal_Statistics/009z000000qs000000/) tool.

Comment: OK so essentially, using either **Filter** or **Focal Statistics** to modify the raster before using the **EV2P** tool with the **Interpolation** option enabled will give me pretty good control of the area of raster values that will be converted to point?
This seems like a very good option, particularly **FS** which appearrs to allow the user a great deal of control over the group of pixels to be summed, averaged, etc. Thanks The_Parser!!!

Comment: Thanks for the approval. Yes you summarise correctly. One thing - I think you should be careful about using the **EV2P** interpolation option once the raster has already been smoothed. It feels a bit like doing a "double smooth" if you see what I mean. But of course as long as you understand what is happening it's your choice.